# Ошибка входа на вебку phpmyadmin

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin, homestead

друзья, столкнулся с проблемой:
Установил homestead, laravel в папку с сайтом, произвел все настройки - тестовый сайт запускается. Далее решил прикрутить БД, взял за основу MySQL, установил в homestead phpmyadmin по инструкции, сделал необходимые манипуляции, страница входа в phpmyadmin стала доступна в браузере. НО, при входе с именем пользователя и паролем из файла .env - выдает сообщение:  Failed to set session cookie. Maybe you are using HTTP instead of HTTPS to access phpMyAdmin.
P.S. Пробовал загрузить с протоколом https - страница не загружается вовсе, только по http.
Вопрос к знатокам: какие настройки я забыл указать, чтобы избежать данную ошибку?

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, не получил ответа, но нашел решение - оно оказалось весьма простым.
Проблема заключалась в версии phpmyadmin - скачал другую версию, появилась другая веб мордочка, все заработало.
P.S. В интернете самый популярный ответ по моей ошибке - это чистка кеша браузера и куков. Мне это не помогло